# Why am I getting a constant for alpha when I take the derivative of my objective function?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to solve this simple optimization problem:

Minimize $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ over $\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{9}y^2-1=0$

I get

$L = x^2+y^2+\alpha(\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{1}{9}y^2-1)$

then

$0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 2x+\frac{1}{2}\alpha x$  $\rightarrow$ x=0

$0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 2y+\frac{2}{9}\alpha y$  $\rightarrow$ y=0

So we get $L=-\alpha$ and $0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha}=-1$

Anything to help me understand this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that $2x+\frac12\alpha x=0\Rightarrow x=0\lor \alpha=-4$. How do you get $x=0$ only?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extremum of $f(x,y)$ on the curve when the derivative is zero.
An extremum is either a maximum or a minimum, not necessarily a minimum.

In this particular problem, there are four extrema.
It so happens that two of them occur when $x = 0$ and the other two occur when $y = 0$.

There is no extremum on the curve where $x = y = 0$ simultaneously;
in fact, there is no point on the curve at all where that condition occurs.
Therefore, while setting $x = y = 0$ satisfies both of the equations
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$,
it is not a solution. You need to look for other ways to satisfy those equations, for example by the choice of $\alpha$.